# Change an image's coordinates across a background Java

Tags: java, image, colors, coordinates, bluej

I am working on this code, but I am struggling to figure out how to change the coordinates of an image, in this case, a picture of the earth, in the targetPicture1 (background).

```
import java.awt.*;
public class CopyCatDemo
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("earth.jpg");
    System.out.println("Width: " + sourcePicture.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height: " + sourcePicture.getHeight());
    Picture targetPicture1 = new Picture(400,400);
    targetPicture1.setAllPixelsToAColor(Color.BLACK);

    Pixel sourcePixel, targetPixel = null;
    Color sourceColor, targetColor = null;

    for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(x,y);
            sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
            targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x,y);
            targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);         
        }
    }

    sourcePicture.show();
    targetPicture1.show();
    targetPicture1.write("NewFile.jpg");
 }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

Comment: To start with you are importing an image of variable size and trying to copy it into an image of set size. This will most likely lead to out of bounds exceptions. Also what do you mean by trying to change the image coordinates?

Comment: I want to move the images across the screen. Instead of being in the top left of the screen, I want to move it to the bottom left or top right, etc.

Comment: I am not trying to manipulate the size of the images, but the location it is located in the black background. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use an offset. This way you can dictate where the image will be places when you copy it over.

try something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class CopyCatDemo
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("earth.jpg");
    System.out.println("Width: " + sourcePicture.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height: " + sourcePicture.getHeight());
    Picture targetPicture1 = new Picture(400,400);
    targetPicture1.setAllPixelsToAColor(Color.BLACK);

    int offsetX = 0;
    int offsetY = 0;

    Pixel sourcePixel, targetPixel = null;
    Color sourceColor, targetColor = null;

    for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(x,y);
            sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
            targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(offsetX + x, offsetY + y);
            targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);         
        }
    }

    sourcePicture.show();
    targetPicture1.show();
    targetPicture1.write("NewFile.jpg");
 }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

then lets say you wanted the image to be located in the bottom right of the screen. Simply set you offset accordingly:

```
int offsetX = 400 - sourcePicture.getWidth();
int offsetY = 400 - sourcePicture.getHeight();
```

Then the image will start being drawn its width a height away from the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: When I tried it, it did not work for me. It still is stuck at the top left of the screen.

Comment: Wait it worked now. I just copied and pasted your code.

Comment: @BenRocco whew I was royally confused for a bit there.

Comment: I have another question that would be great if you answered, how would I cut the image in half, like have only the northern hemisphere show for the earth?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but how would i set up a second image and make that be able to move like the first one? Because to make the first picture move, you have the code for the targetPicture1, or does that not matter? I am really sorry to bother you some more.

Comment: create a class for the pictures that are being re-positioned with a function like draw that draws it onto the background.

Comment: Could you please show me? I am trying to do that without making extra classes.

Comment: When I try to add a new picture in, I was trying to copy the same format as the sourcePicture, and I keep getting an error saying that the coordinates are out of bounds. Is that because the image is a different size? Would I need to make a new nested loop?

Answer (score 1):

To answer @Ben Rocco's second question:

> I have another question that would be great if you answered, how would I cut the image in half, like have only the northern hemisphere show for the earth?

you need to change the start point for your java loop. Lets only print the bottom half of the photo:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class CopyCatDemo
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("earth.jpg");
    System.out.println("Width: " + sourcePicture.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height: " + sourcePicture.getHeight());
    Picture targetPicture1 = new Picture(400,400);
    targetPicture1.setAllPixelsToAColor(Color.BLACK);

    int offsetX = 0;
    int offsetY = 0;

    Pixel sourcePixel, targetPixel = null;
    Color sourceColor, targetColor = null;

    for(int y = sourcePicture.getHeight()/2; y < sourcePicture.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(x,y);
            sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
            targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(offsetX + x, offsetY + y);
            targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);         
        }
    }

    sourcePicture.show();
    targetPicture1.show();
    targetPicture1.write("NewFile.jpg");
 }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

then we need to change the offset for Y:

```
int offsetX = 400 - sourcePicture.getWidth();
int offsetY = 400 - sourcePicture.getHeight()/2;
```

tada!

Comment: That makes so much sense, I feel dumb.